# Save to iPhone homescreen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, save, homescreen

Is it possible to save several "instances" of app on homescreen? So just as Safari on mobile has feature save to homescreen.

What I need is that for example app has 5 textfields and you fill those textfields with data. I  "Save to homescreen" with that particular data in textfields. Now I have 2 icons on homescreen (first one with empty textfields) and now second which is added and that opens up with filled textfields.

User can "Save to homescreen" with specific data as much as he likes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Apps can't add things to the homescreen.

Comment: Thats what I thought, was just curious because client insisted from me. Although its not actually add things but add new icon of self with different options when opened, thats not possible right?

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to be able to do it. The only ways to get things on the home screen are to install through the app store, install through iTunes/xcode, or save to home screen from safari. Maybe you could if the phone was jailbroken, but I don't know anything about that.